# How to programmatically get newly created build definitions in TFS?

Tags: c#, tfs-sdk, build-definition

Currently I am querying the build definitions by project and getting all of them.  My code (simplified) looks something like the following

```
var server = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("url"));
server.EnsureAuthenticated();
var buildServer = (IBuildServer)server.GetService(typeof(IBuildServer));
var buildDefinitions = buildServer.QueryBuildDefinitions("Project_name");
```

What I want is to get only the build definitions added after a particular date, say last Friday.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply (example for last seven days)

```
var buildDefinitions = buildServer.QueryBuildDefinitions("Project_name").Where(bd=>bd.DateCreated.Date>=DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7).Date);
```

Comment: I cannot find the DateCreated property in the builddefinition

Comment: which TFS version are you using ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.client.ibuilddefinition(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hmm ... I am using 2010 version. Let me see if I can update that.